# How do you fix the index after using the .reset_index and pivot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, seaborn

So I was trying a cool way to present heat maps. I understand that there is a way to properly organise and pivot the data before working with it. I used the following code.

````
ct_counts = df.groupby(['VClass', 'fuelType']).size()
ct_counts = ct_counts.reset_index()
ct_counts = ct_counts.pivot(index = 'VClass', columns = 'fuelType')
sb.heatmap(ct_counts, annot = True, fmt = 'd');```
````

[heatmap result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRtU4.png)

How can I get rid of the '0' and 'None' labels associated with the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be simplify with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), so also are removed `0` and `None` values:

```
ct_counts = df.groupby(['VClass', 'fuelType']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

sb.heatmap(ct_counts, annot = True, fmt = 'd')
```